# Can’t get .desktop file to run python script

Tags: scripts, python, .desktop

**EDIT 9:** Before writing an answer saying to change `Exec=/home/insertUsernameHere/volumeGUI/volumeGUI.py` to `Exec=something or another`, the `.desktop` file `Exec=` code isn't the problem as it runs fine with `gtk-launch`. The problem is that it doesn't run from Show Applications, it just does nothing. Also **please** watch my [screen capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XkjEZ.gif) so you can see exactly what the problem is.

I’ve been trying (for a couple of hours now) to get a `.desktop` file to run my python script, but when I click on the icon in the applications window, nothing happens.

Here’s my .desktop code:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Exec=/home/insertUsernameHere/volumeGUI/volumeGUI.py
Name=Volume GUI
Icon=/home/insertUsernameHere/volumeGUI/volumeGUI_Logo.png
```

Note that when I run
`/home/insertUsernameHere/volumeGUI/volumeGUI.py` in the terminal it works fine.

**EDIT:** Here's my python code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from tkinter import *
from tkinter.font import *
import subprocess

top = Tk()
top.resizable(False, False)
top.title("Python Volume Controller")
padx = 10
pady = 10
myFont = Font(family = "helvetica", size = 16, weight = "bold")

volumeTextVariable = StringVar()
currentVolumeText = Label(top, textvariable = volumeTextVariable, font = myFont)
currentVolumeText.grid(row = 1, column = 0, columnspan = 2, padx=padx, pady=pady)

volumeIncrement = 2

def volumeUp(volume):
    if (volume + volumeIncrement) <= 100:
        subprocess.call("pactl set-sink-volume 0 +" + str(volumeIncrement) + r"%", shell=True)
        volumeTextVariable.set("Current Volume: " + getVolume() + r"%")

def volumeDown(volume):
    if (volume - volumeIncrement) >= 0:
        subprocess.call("pactl set-sink-volume 0 -" + str(volumeIncrement) + r"%", shell=True)
        volumeTextVariable.set("Current Volume: " + getVolume() + r"%")

def getVolume():
    try:
        volume = subprocess.Popen("amixer get Master |grep % |awk '{print $4}'|sed 's/[^0-9]//g'", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True).communicate()[0].decode("utf-8")[:-1]
    except:
        volume = -404
    return volume

volumeTextVariable.set("Current Volume: " + getVolume() + r"%")

volUpButton = Button(top, text = "Volume Up", command = lambda: volumeUp(int(getVolume())), font = myFont)
volDownButton = Button(top, text = "Volume Down", command = lambda: volumeDown(int(getVolume())), font = myFont)
volUpButton.grid(row = 2, column = 1, padx=padx, pady=pady)
volDownButton.grid(row = 2, column = 0, padx=padx, pady=pady)

top.mainloop()
```

**EDIT 6:** GIF of me running the `.desktop` file in the command line with `gtk-launch volumeGUI.desktop` and it working, but not working when trying to launch it from `Show Applications`
[Screen Capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XkjEZ.gif)

**EDIT 7:** I have since improved my python code: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/QF6PVrSPSy/

**EDIT 8:** I changed `Exec=/home/insertUsernameHere/volumeGUI/volumeGUI.py` to `Exec=bash -c "/home/insertUsernameHere/volumeGUI/volumeGUI.py 2>&1 > ~/logfile.txt"` as per a suggestion and when I either run it with `gtk-launch` or try and run it from Show Applications the log file is empty.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82367/discussion-on-question-by-sgtoddball-cant-get-desktop-file-to-run-python-scrip).

Comment: No idea what has been written in the meantime, but works instantly here. So we have a few options: 1. paths are incorrect (try paste the icon path in e.g. firefox, see if it shows) 2. script is not executable (needs to be if you don't call the interpreter) 3. If you use the .desktop file from your desktop, it needs to be executabel and trusted. Can't think of anything else. Encoding isn't needed btw, deprecated if I remember well.

Comment: @JacobVlijm If you look in the chat you'll see I'm able to run the `.desktop` file with gtk-launch in the command line as per a suggestion but I'm still unable to launch it by clicking on it in either Show Applications, the bar down the left of the screen, or Files.

Comment: @SgtOddball No clue what `gtk-launch` exactly does, but could you please confirm/double check the paths match exactly, paste the icon path in a browser. Just to make sure, but you are aware you need to double-click on the icon if it is on your desktop, to show it in the launcher, it needs to be in `~/.local/share/applications`, right? As said, it works instantly here.

Comment: @JacobVlijm it's in `~/.local/share/applications` and I can see it in Show Applications, if you watch the screen capture GIF in edit 6 you'll see exactly what happens. edit: I don't know what `gtk-launch` does either, it was suggested in the comments that have since been moved to a chat.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing
Exec=/script.py
to
Exec=python3 /script.py

I have several Java programs that I run via .desktop files. Some even get executed on boot... Sorry so short, posting via my phone.

Comment: I am able to run the `.desktop` file with `gtk-launch`, the code in the `.desktop` file works.

Comment: The only other thing is executable permissions for the .desktop file... Like I said, I have several of these that I use regularly. I can execute all of them with several methods... I tried! Lol

Comment: A screenshot of the files permissions: https://imgur.com/a/MvOZZUp

Comment: Sorry, Bill, this has been tried before. There's whole discussion in the chat and comments, and 3 deleted answers that mentioned this.

Comment: I tried this and works for some py scripts.